# Unable to create foreign key constraint MySql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables like these:

```
'CREATE TABLE `preoperativeassessments` (
  `Id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `SurgeonName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `SurgeonExperience` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AnesthetistName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateOfBirthYear` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Gender` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SurgeryDate` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HospitalId` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `PatientId` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `SurgeonId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `TheaterId` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AssessmentDate` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BodyStructureId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `MethodId` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EthnicityId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `FK_PreOperativeAssessments_Hospitals_HospitalId_idx` (`HospitalId`),
  KEY `FK_PreOperativeAssessments_Patients_PatientId_idx` (`PatientId`),
  KEY `FK_PreOperativeAssessments_Users_SurgeonId_idx` (`SurgeonId`),
  KEY `FK_PreOperativeAssessments_BodyStructures_BodyStructureId_idx` (`BodyStructureId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PreOperativeAssessments_BodyStructures_BodyStructureId` FOREIGN KEY (`BodyStructureId`) REFERENCES `bodystructures` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PreOperativeAssessments_Hospitals_HospitalId` FOREIGN KEY (`HospitalId`) REFERENCES `hospitals` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PreOperativeAssessments_Patients_PatientId` FOREIGN KEY (`PatientId`) REFERENCES `patients` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PreOperativeAssessments_Users_SurgeonId` FOREIGN KEY (`SurgeonId`) REFERENCES `abpusers` (`Id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'


CREATE TABLE `ethnicities` (
   `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `Description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and I try to add foreign key constraint using this:

```
ALTER TABLE casemix.preoperativeassessments ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PreOperativeAssessments_Ethnicities_EthnicityId  FOREIGN KEY (EthnicityId) REFERENCES casemix.ethnicities (Id) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
```

But I keep getting this error: "Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint"

What could be the issue here?

Comment: There are no keys on id in ethnicities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are the first columns in the same order.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html or a primary key